# LEFT JOIN optimizations

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I'm wondering if it's better to do joined query like that :

```
SELECT * FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1=table2.id
    AND table2.field2="mystring"
WHERE table2.field2="mystring"
```

Instead of simply doing it :

```
SELECT * FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1=table2.id
WHERE table2.field2="mystring"
```

Is the MySQL engine doing this optimizations for me or is it better to do it explicitly ?

Does :

```
SELECT * FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table2.field2="mystring" AND table2.id=table1.field1
```

has the same effect, will results be identical ?

Edit: Some more precisions, my questions are :

- i assume the 3 above queries are equivalent in term of given results. Are they really (especially the third) ?
- i'm wondering if the engine treat them equally in terms of performances (in other words do i have to worry wich one to use) ?

Comment: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Answer (score 2):

This will still show records of table1 if table2.field2!="mystring"

```
SELECT * FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1=table2.id
    AND table2.field2="mystring"
```

This will not show records of table1 if table2.field2!="mystring"

```
SELECT * FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1=table2.id
WHERE table2.field2="mystring"
```

The output can be different. The first query in this situation could show more results then the second.

Comment: To compare performance between these to types of queries you could use the `EXPLAIN` syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Thx for the answer but the first query you gave isn't in the scope of my question. Here is the orignal query :

    SELECT * FROM table1
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.field1=table2.id
        AND table2.field2="mystring"
    WHERE table2.field2="mystring"